# Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

When i hardcode the url in the code it works. I am trying to get the hostname and append the request. It gives this error,

**Invalid** **URI**: The URI scheme is not valid.

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
Source Error: 
Line 44:         string request = url.Scheme + "//" + url.Host + ":" + url.Port +"/accounts1/asp2netbridge.asp?sessVar=";
Line 45:       
Line 46:         HttpWebRequest _myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(request + sessionValue));
Line 47:         _myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
Line 48:         _myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Here is the code:

```
  Uri url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  string request = url.Scheme + "//" + url.Host + ":" + url.Port +"/accounts1/asp2netbridge.asp?sessVar=";      
  HttpWebRequest _myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(request + sessionValue));
```

Comment: what about sessionValue is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ":" before "//"

> string request = url.Scheme + "://" + url.Host + ":" + url.Port
>   +"/accounts1/asp2netbridge.asp?sessVar=";